# Selenium - Searching Element by xPath is not found during execution but it is found on Browser

Tags: java, selenium, xpath

I use chrome driver and selenium with java.

This is on my java code. It is executed while I am on that specific page I am interested in.

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@name='firstName']")).sendKeys("John");
```

This is on the website, on that specific page.

```
<input type="text" id="fname" name="firstName" placeholder="First Name" data-reactid="....">
```

the problem is not even about setting the text to the input, it is that it doesn't find the input field at all. Here is the error

```
org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//input[@name='firstName']"}
Command duration or timeout: 20.04 seconds
For documentation on this error, please visit: http://seleniumhq.org/exceptions/no_such_element.html
Build info: version: '2.53.0', revision: '35ae25b', time: '2016-03-15 16:57:40'
```

As you can see from the error I have implicit wait of 20 seconds and I can see that the page and fields have loaded during that time.

So the weird thing is that when I open chrome and inspect element and search by xPath, with the same exact command I can find the field (On the same page that my java crashed on the same chrome window). I can find all other elements except from the input field.

Is there any way to troubleshoot this? Are input fields not supported this way through selenium?! I am not sure what to assume, any ideas greatly appreciated!

Comment: maybe your input is inside an iframe. You need to switch your driver to inspect elements inside this frame before try to find the element

Comment: Yeah it is, and I wasn't even aware that I should do this. Spot on! Thanks so much!

Comment: Sometimes can be another werid error. So I didn't posted the awnser, only asked you to check the frame. Now, I posted an example how to manage iframes inside your tests. Good luck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to handling iframes to acess your element:

```
// This way allows you to select an iframe using 'By' and access it.
driver.switchTo().frame(driver.findElement(By.id("frameId")));

// Now you can only handle the iframe elements, like your request
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@name='firstName']")).sendKeys("John");

// After execute all that you need inside the iframe, 
// returns you to default html, outside the iframe.
driver.switchTo().defaultContent();
```